# mypy does not recognize derived generic with different variance than the base class

Tags: python, generics, mypy, python-typing, generic-variance

When type checking the following code block with `mypy` an error is raised.

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


class Employee:
    pass


class Manager(Employee):
    pass


T_co = TypeVar('T_co', Employee, Manager, covariant=True)
T_contra = TypeVar('T_contra', Employee, Manager, contravariant=True)


class Base(Generic[T_contra]):
    pass


class Derived(Base[T_co]):
    pass


def consume_base_manager(_: Base[Manager]) -> None: ...
def consume_base_employee(_: Base[Employee]) -> None: ...
def consume_derived_manager(_: Derived[Manager]) -> None: ...
def consume_derived_employee(_: Derived[Employee]) -> None: ...


base_manager: Base[Manager]
base_employee: Base[Employee]
derived_manager: Derived[Manager]
derived_employee: Derived[Employee]

consume_base_manager(base_employee)
consume_base_manager(base_manager)
consume_base_manager(derived_manager)
consume_base_manager(derived_employee)

consume_base_employee(base_employee)
consume_base_employee(derived_manager)
consume_base_employee(derived_employee)

consume_derived_manager(derived_manager)

consume_derived_employee(derived_manager)
consume_derived_employee(derived_employee)
```

Output:
`error: Argument 1 to "consume_base_employee" has incompatible type "Derived[Manager]"; expected "Base[Employee]"`

Out of the four functions and four argument types, I called every function with what I thought to be every valid argument but `mypy` gave me an error on `consume_base_employee(derived_manager)`. This is weird to me because according to [PEP 483](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#covariance-and-contravariance) this should be valid.

> In complex definitions of derived generics, variance only determined from type variables used. A complex example:
>
> ```
> T_co = TypeVar('T_co', Employee, Manager, covariant=True)
> T_contra = TypeVar('T_contra', Employee, Manager, contravariant=True)
>
> class Base(Generic[T_contra]):
>     ...
>
> class Derived(Base[T_co]):
>     ...
> ```
>
> A type checker finds from the second declaration that `Derived[Manager]` is a subtype of `Derived[Employee]`, and `Derived[t1]` is a subtype of `Base[t1]`. If we denote the is-subtype-of relationship with `<`, then the full diagram of subtyping for this case will be:
>
> ```
> Base[Manager]    >  Base[Employee]
>     v                    v
> Derived[Manager] <  Derived[Employee]
> ```
>
> so that a type checker will also find that, e.g., `Derived[Manager]` is a subtype of `Base[Employee]`.

What is even weirder to me is that the line that raises an error is the one situation that is explicitly stated in the PEP that should work.

Did I misunderstand the intended meaning of the PEP, is there a mistake in the PEP or is this a bug in `mypy`?

Comment: I think you are right. This seems to be an error in `mypy`. Have you checked their [issue tracker](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/) to see, if this was mentioned there already?